# Jenkins throws FindFailed: exception Sikuli

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins, sikuli-script

I am using sikuli-script.jar to click on images link with Selenium WebDriver (With TestNG framework). The same is working fine when i run my code Run as TestNGSuite or with ant run (from the command prompt).
Below is my code:-

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();   
driver.get("http://google.com");
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1366, 768));     
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("Title is " +driver.getTitle());
System.out.println("Browser opened");
try {


Screen s=new Screen();
Pattern image=new Pattern("D:\\LoyalityFiles\\gmail\\1476714460371.png");

s.find(image);
s.click(image);
System.out.println("clicked on gmail");
System.out.println("Title of this page is " +driver.getTitle()+" and url is " +driver.getCurrentUrl());

driver.quit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

issue:- While running this code via jenkins it throws :-

```
FindFailed: can not find P(D:\LoyalityFiles\gmail\1476714460371.png) S: 0.7 on the screen.
   [testng]   Line 1574, in file Region.java
   [testng] 
   [testng]     at org.sikuli.script.Region.handleFindFailed(Region.java:1574)
   [testng]     at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:1682)
   [testng]     at org.sikuli.script.Region.find(Region.java:1590)
   [testng]     at sikuli.ImageC.Google(ImageC.java:33)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   [testng]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
   [testng]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
   [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1355)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1324)
```

please note:- i am running jenkins as windows service. pls suggest!!

Comment: Where is your test running? Is that the same machine where Jenkins is? Does that machine has a physical screen attached to it where you can see what's happening?

Comment: I am running my jenkins on my local machine where my code hosts. i meant both jenkins and code are on the same machine and i am running jenikns as windows service.

Comment: Running Jenkins as a service might be your issue here. Find the Java process responsible for Jenkins and kill it. Then manually start Jenkins again from command line or something. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

SikuliX cannot find your pattern on the Screen during 3 seconds (default value, `Settings.AutoWaitTimeout`) and throws `FindFailed` exception. Try to raise `Settings.AutoWaitTimeout` or implement own smart waiter instead of `screen.find()`

Comment: :- Could you pls write code, which i need to use instead of screen.find()